Why are planets cold?
Excuse me for me ignorance, I'm just fiddling around this question for quite a while.
The question of course is not limited to planets. Boiling down to, why isn't the universe heated up by now to thousands of degrees by now.
As far as I know, photons can only lose energy in certain ways. On larger scales, the standard answer to this problem is, the expansion of the universe itself, which kind of stretches the wavelength of photons, effectively lowers the energy.
Other possible ways could be compton scattering or raman scattering, which certainly can not happen within our solar system enough, to explain, why our "outer planets" are getting colder and colder.
If photons cannot lose energy, why aren't all planets heated up by now, including all objects in the Kuiper belt or the Oort cloud?
Everything should be under constant bombardment of photons for about 4.5 billion years.

Photons from the cosmic microwave background outnumber other photons overall. This would mean an object in deepest space would achieve a radiative equilibrium (i.e. where objects both absorb and emit radiation in equal amounts) at the same temperature as the cosmic microwave background of 2.7 Kelvin.
The planets are warmer than this for multiple reasons. First, they are close to a source of luminosity, second they may still be hot from their formation process, third they may have interiors heat sources such as radioactive decay or gravitational contraction. For these reasons, planets reach an equilibrium at higher temperatures and are often radiating much more energy than they absorb (e.g. Jupiter).

Lets assume just space and objects which emit radiation (light/photons amongst). Let's assume further we have a solar system like ours, but all planets do not have any atmosphere, just plain rocks.
Would all planets reach the same temperature in time or would the temperature fall by distance to the sun? If temperature falls, why?

@jAndy the equilibrium temperature falls with distance to the star. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_equilibrium_temperature

I still don't really grasp it. You mentioning that planets are "close" to a source of luminosity. But shouldn't the factor of distance explicitly shouldn't play any role at all, if photons cannot lose energy within that rather "short" distance?

@jAndy Obviously not as many photons hit a planet if it is futher away from a star. The distance dependence of the equilibrium temperature is made clear in the wikipedia link I gave you.

Objects can absorb, emit, and scatter (reflect) photons as well. So although everything is under constant bombardment of photons, those objects are also constantly radiating photons away.

So does the earth.
But that doesn't really answer the question, why objects further away from the sun, are getting gradually colder?

@jAndy Objects further from the sun, in general, are not gradually getting colder. However, all else being equal, an object further from the sun will be colder because it is receiving less photons than objects closer to the sun.

Even if that is open to discussion, how many "less" photons an object further away from the sun receives. We are "only" talking about distances within a solar system, not on intergalactic or cosmic distance, so, regardless of how many photons an object receives, that all should heat up over time.
Unless of course, radiation from those objects is causing the object to lose energy faster than receiving, which again would rise the question, how many photons are necessary for heating up any given object without further influences (gas, atmosphere).

@jAndy The amount of photons an object receives from the sun, due to its distance from the sun, scales like $1/r^2.$ So if Planet A is 3 times further from the sun than planet B it will receive $1/9$ the amount of photons. What will happen is that the photons leaving a planet due to radiation will come into equilibrium and be the same as the rate of photons received. So the object will reach some constant temperature $T$ and stay there.
